# Haskell, combining subcommands with other parsing option in optparse-generic

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, optparse-generic

I'm using [optparse-generic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic) to parse the command line arguments of a program called `example`. I am combining labeled and unlabeled datatypes (as [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375556/haskell-unnamed-command-line-arguments-for-optparse-generic)).

```hs
data Labeled = Labeled { foo :: Maybe Int <?> "Help about foo" } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ParseRecord Labeled

data Unlabeled = Unlabeled (String <?> "Help about the mandatory last argument.") deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ParseRecord Unlabeled

data Mixed = Mixed Labeled Unlabeled deriving (Show)

instance ParseRecord Mixed where
    parseRecord = Mixed <$> parseRecord <*> parseRecord
```

It generates the following help text.

```sh
Usage: example [--foo INT] STRING

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
  --foo INT                Help about foo 
  STRING                   Help about the mandatory last argument.
```

Now I would like to extend `example` to support different modular tasks. For example, as shown in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic-1.1.0/docs/Options-Generic.html), let's assume `example` can perform a `Create` and a `Kill` task. Each task may need different command line options.

```hs
data ExampleTasks
    = Create { name :: Text, duration :: Maybe Int }
    | Kill   { name :: Text }
    deriving (Generic, Show)
```

**Question 1:** 
I would like to combine these things such that a user can now additionally select the task which will be performed by `example`. How can this be achieved?

For example, I want to be able to call `example` as follows:

```sh
./example --foo 42 --task kill --name=foo "the last mandatory argument"
```

or

```sh
./example --task create --name=foo --duration 60 /bin/bash
```

The help text should look similar to something like the following (or maybe a nicer and clearer structure):

```sh
Usage: example [--foo INT] (--task TASKNAME TASKOPTIONS) STRING

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
  --foo INT                Help about foo 
  STRING                   Help about the mandatory last argument.

Available tasks:
  create                   Help about create
  kill                     Help about kill

Available taskoptions for create:
  --name STRING            Help about the name in create
  --duration ...           In seconds

Available taskoptions for kill
  --name STRING            Help about the name
```

**Question 2:** Can the whole `--task` argument and its parameters be optional? For example, I'd like to call:

```sh
./example --foo 42 "the last mandatory argument"
```

Comment: I think optparse-generic is pretty limited in what sorts of types in can automatically create a parser for. The docs say it doesn't support nested record fields. You may have to write the parser yourself with optparse-applicative. See [subparser and command](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.12.1.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html).

Comment: Is your question related to https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Optparse-Generic-Library/issues/18 ?